# How close can refractive index be to one? Classical vs Quantum calculation?

Tags: laser, refraction, vacuum

How close can the refraction index of a gas be to one such that it can still be used in classical calculations?

For example imagine we have $n-1=10^{-22}$. In [1] I find

$n-1=\frac{\gamma_{mol}P}{2 k T}=\frac{\gamma_{mol}N}{2 V}$

where $\gamma_{mol}=2\times 10^{-29} m^3$ is the molecular polarizability (for air), $P$ the pressure, $T$ the temperature, $k$ the Boltzmann constant and $N$ is the numbers of molecules in the volume $V$. I have assumed the ideal gas law in the equation.

For $n-1=10^{-22}$ we therefore get

$\frac{N}{V}=10^7\frac{1}{m^3}=10\frac{1}{cm^3}$

We have 10 molecules in a cube of size $1\times cm^3$! Is it in this case still possible to use this $n=1+10^{-22}$ is a classical calculation? Does the answer depend on the photon wavelength?

If I cannot use a classical calculation what would I have to do in order to for example calculate the phase shift by a laser beam that propagates in this low density gas?

Many thanks in advance!

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0782

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not really about physics, although it uses its language...

Comment: Refractive indices that are not exactly 1 are used in classical optics all the time. I'm unclear what the question is about.

Comment: I want to know how close it can be to one such that a classical calculation still holds! It can never be exactly one due to for example QED effects. QED effects can contribute to the refractive index (S.L.Adler,Ann.Phys.(N.Y.)67,599(1971)), however this happens only at very strong fields and gives a very small contribution to n-1